# Notice of bounty disappeared from question

Tags: support, bounties, serial-voting

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284051/buttons-dont-show-up-or-remove-each-other-in-gridlayout/37335515#37335515) on Stack Overflow that had a bounty of 50 before I posted the accepted answer. I know that if the asker does not manually award the bounty answer, then it will automatically be awarded to the accepted answer after 7 days + a 1 day grace period assuming there is an answer that has been accepted.

I am trying to understand what happened to the notice of the bounty on this question. I would expect it to continue to be displayed on the site in the hopes of attracting the "best" answer. I have looked at the timeline for the question and don't even see where the bounty was started. It seems to have just disappeared.

Can someone explain what happened? Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW, in [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37284051/timeline), the `notice added` and `notice removed` are talking about the bounty. Same in the revision history as well.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I noticed that but was not sure that it was about the bounty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bounty was removed due to voting irregularities on the user's account - they did not actually have the amount of reputation needed to offer that bounty once the inappropriate votes were reversed.